# Partition a row over (num) rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have data of the form:

```
ID         name     date    count
---------------------------------
1           A     1/1/2015    3
2           B     1/4/2015    2
3           C     1/6/2015    4
4           D     1/10/2015   2
```

Which I would like to turn into something like...

```
1 A 1/1/2015
1 A 1/2/2015
1 A 1/3/2015
2 B 1/4/2015
2 B 1/5/2015
3 C 1/6/2015
...
```

I believe this is possible using a partition query, but I'm having a real problem understanding the [examples I find on the MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql). I need to use `ROW_NUMBER` in `DATEADD`, but I can't figure out how to get it to return the right number of rows, say 3 for the first case. The `TerritoryName` example seems close...

In the worst case I can do this in VBA code, and I also know of solutions using tables filled with dates, but I think this is something I should know how to do in the SELECT if possible.

**UPDATE:** I am not allowed to change anything in the original database (a licensing issue). I could use a #blah, but would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use built-in `spt_values` table, if selecting on `Type`='P', `Number` returns consecutive numbers between 0 and 2047.
If column `count` contains reliable value of day count query could be:

```
select t.id, t.name, dateadd(d, numbers.Number, t.date) as date
from t
join master..spt_values as numbers
on numbers.Type = 'P'
and numbers.Number < t.count
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62aee/2

Comment: I'm glad it helped. spt_values can come in handy if you can't modify database, if you're able to modify, usually dedicated table is added with consecutive numbers, such table can then be indexed and contain any number of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Indeed. In this case 2047 was "big enough" and it appears to be clustered on that, so the performance was excellent.

Answer (score 2):

This is where a tally table is the right tool for the job. I keep one as a view on my system. It is insanely fast.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now we just need some sample data and we can then join to our tally table.

```
set dateformat mdy --you really should use ANSI standard YYYYMMDD

insert @Something values
(1, 'A', '1/1/2015', 3)
,(2, 'B', '1/4/2015', 2)
,(3, 'C', '1/6/2015', 4)
,(4, 'D', '1/10/2015', 2)

select s.*
    , DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, s.SomeDate)
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= s.SomeCount
```

Since you can't create a view you can trim this cte down a bit also to fit your current needs and have the cte be in your query. Something like this.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1
    )
select s.*
    , DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, s.SomeDate)
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= s.SomeCount
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the permissions to change anything in the database - that's "legal" permissions, not logical. But perhaps I could use this as a sub-query in the second one? Oh, I just realized I clipped the part where I said that.

Comment: Sure. Notice it is a cte? Just make the cte inline.

Comment: You could also create that view in another database and join to it just the same.

Answer (score 0):

If not all dates are represented, and you only want to list dates that are in the table, I think something like the following would work:

```
SELECT ranknum, itemname, itemdate
FROM (SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.itemdate ORDER BY allitems.itemname) ranknum
     , t.id
     , allitems.itemname
     , t.itemdate
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT itemname FROM tablename) allitems 
         LEFT JOIN tablename t ON allitems.itemname = t.itemname) ranked
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ranknum, itemdate
```